# How to display Laravel route the same on a homestead machine and when served locally

Tags: php, laravel, routes, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to serve my Laravel application from a Homestead machine with the following `Homestead.yaml`:

```
name: homestead-fontys
ip: "192.168.10.12"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: c:/Users/karin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/Users/karin/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: c:/Users/karin/Documents/uni/work/develop/laravel-forum/forum/
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: exampleurl.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
      type: apache
      php: "7.2"

databases:
    - forum

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

I have the following routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/hello-world', function () {
    return view('helloworld');
});
```

When I serve the website from git bash I can go to http://localhost:8000/ to view the first URL. However, if I go to http://exampleurl.test I get a `No input file specified.` To access the welcome page I have to append `/index.php` to the URL. I have not figured out what the URL is for the /hello-world one when run by Homestead.

How can I make sure that the welcome page is served on the URL `http://exampleurl.test` and hello-world is available at http://exampleurl.test/hello-world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it the following way:

1.edited the `.htaccess` file in my `/public` directory with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2. Renamed `server.php` in the project root to `index.php`
3. ran `vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like re-write rules are not properly configured in apache, so you need to double-check that.

Yes, you will need to access everything through `index.php` (which is also called the front controller), so to access hello-world you'll need to visit `http://exampleurl.test/index.php/hello-world`

Comment: I am using Homestead, I am not sure if it is okay to change the apache service. 
Even if I type http://exampleurl.test/index.php/hello-world, it is giving me ```No input file specified.```